# How to add checkBox in Dialog and get value?

Tags: checkbox, dialog, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to add a  *CheckBox* in my **Dialog**.

I used this code:

```
Dialog dialog;
DialogField dialogField;
NoYesId checkValue;
;
dialog = new Dialog("New dialog with checkBox");

dialogField = dialog.addFieldValue(identifierStr(NoYes) , checkValue);
checkValue= dialogField.value();
dialog.run();
info(strfmt("Value %1" , checkValue));
```

So, in *Debug* I see the value of the variable (checkValue) always NO .

On web-tutorial I saw this code:

```
dialog.addFieldValue(typeid(NoYes), NoYes::Yes, "tip");
```

But I have an error *Method typeid not exist* .

What is the way?
Thanks all,

enjoy!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only use `typeId` (AX 2009 and before) or `extendedTypeStr` (AX 2012) on extended data types (EDT), not enums like `NoYes`. It can be used on `NoYesId`, as it is an EDT.

```
dialog.addFieldValue(typeid(NoYesId), NoYes::Yes, "Check");
```

You must call run before you can meaningful acquire the value.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog("New dialog with checkBox");
NoYesId checkValue = NoYes::No;
DialogField dialogField = dialog.addFieldValue(extendedTypeStr(NoYesId), checkValue, "Check it");
if (dialog.run())
{
    checkValue = dialogField.value();
    info(strfmt("Value %1" , checkValue));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `enumStr()` if extended data type does not exists for enum, e.g:

```
dialogField = dialog.addFieldValue(enumStr(NoYes), checkValue);
```

Comment: Thanks @Aliaksandr Maksimau, nice advice.

Answer (score 0):

identifierStr instead of extendedTypeStr worked for me (Ax 2012)

Comment: This will cause a best practice warning `"Consider use of more specialized intrinsic functionality"`